# creating new pyenv virtualenv but all old packages are still there

Tags: python, pip, pyenv

I used to

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.8.12 newenv
pyenv activate newenv
pip list
```

-> and there was no package install, which is good since we want to start fresh

Now, I don't know why, all my packages are present. Pip list contains dozens of packages.
There is nothing in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: `pip list` is empty?

Comment: @9769953 no it's not. That's my problem.

Comment: What is the output of `which pip`? Also `which python`?

Comment: @a_guest `which pip` /home/user/.local/bin/pip

`which python` python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3.8

Comment: So your virtual environment is apparently not activated, or the activation didn't adjust the PATH properly.

Comment: Thanks @a_guest , what could be the cause of it? PATH is /home/user/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: Perhaps you need to reinstall pyenv. There's more in my PATH, e.g. `~/.pyenv/shims` and `~/.pyenv/bin`.